# Set the Start Menu to default-select the first item on the list?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I love the Start menu Search in Windows 7.

Usually, for me, the first search result is always the one I want, but annoyingly, the default selection is always "Show more results". I understand why and what its uses are, but I'd like to know if there's a way I can have the search always highlight the first result instead so I can simply press "Enter" and not have to use the arrow keys or the mouse.

I thought about Googling this, but I was unsure how to phrase it in a way that makes sense.

I'm comfortable editing the Registry if that's what's needed.

See the image for clarification: I've typed "i lived.mp3" and it highlights not the first result, but "See more results" instead.

[image]

Comment: strange, the first result *is* highlighted on my Windows 7 install...

Comment: I've added an image to clarify, I hope that helps.

Comment: i get [this...](http://imgur.com/WEhWMnK) what happens if you search for an application?

Comment: You're right, it works fine for applications. I don't understand why it's not working for files.

Comment: @Harsha K: what is the theme?

Comment: The theme isn't interfering with it, I tried with just regular Aero. It appears that it has to do with files vs programs.

Comment: @Harsha K: I mean, what is the themes name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Windows 7 selects the first item from the list *if* it's a 'Program', but not if it's just a File.

I do not think you can change this behavior, however, you can *remove* the "See more results" option from the list.  Sadly, this does not make the first option the default selection - instead it makes pressing 'Enter' do nothing.  Not ideal, but it does prevent accidentally picking 'See more results' and it lets you select the first item in the list with 1 less 'down' key press.

To remove the "See more results" option, go [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/211057-start-menu-add-remove-see-more-results-link-search-box.html), or manually add a DWORD named `NoSearchEverywhereLinkInStartMenu` with a value of `1` to key `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer]`.

Also, Win7 will auto-select any file which is in the 'StartMenu' location - so if you just have a few commonly used files that you want to be auto-selected for you, you can create shortcuts to them in your `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` folder.  Those shortcuts will show up as 'Programs' in the Start Menu and therefor can be auto-selected.

This 'Shortcuts to non-Program in StartMenu Folder' trick can be semi-automated with the use of a 3rd party utility called [ShortPopUp](http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/ShortPopUp/) (or others).  I have a few shortcuts to ShortPopUp (with an ini config file as a cmdLine parameter) which generates menus for certain commonly-used document folders.  This allows keyboard-only navigation for many of my commonly used files.

Comment: Thank you. I've picked this as the answer because it explains why its happening. I appreciate the regedit, it worked great, and I guess it's better than nothing.

Comment: This makes me sad.. I have an excel file I use all the time and it won't highlight my shortcut. Maybe I'll see if it'll work if I make a BAT file?

Comment: abelito - Win7 will auto-select any file which is in the 'StartMenu' location - so if you just have a few files you want it to auto-select for you, create shortcuts to them in your "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu" folder and those shortcuts will show up as 'Programs' in the Start Menu and therefor can be auto-selected!

Answer (score 0):

it seems like a problem with some of your programs.. You might have some sort of plugin that messes it up.

It works as you describe out of the box.

Comment: It appears to work for Applications, but nothing else.